# Excel formula for increasing number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I write Excel formula for this:

```
TC-SM-001
TC-SM-002
TC-SM-003
... etc.
```

I would like to start it from an arbitrary position in the sheet and then to have the incrementation. Also, I would like the numbers to increment automatically if I delete or add the row somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of these in a cell somewhere on the worksheet.

```
="TC-SM-"&text(row(1:1), "000")
=text(row(1:1), "TC-\S\M-000")
```

Fill down as necessary. Replace `ROW(1:1)` with any other starting or seeding number you prefer to start at; e.g. `ROW(95:95)` to start at TC-SM-095.

[image: TEXT concatenation and sequential numbers]

If the above formulas are giving you an error, your computer system's regional settings may have a semi-colon as the *list delimiter*.

```
="TC-SM-"&text(row(1:1); "000")
=text(row(1:1); "TC-\S\M-000")
```

Comment: I've added a note about some regional settings using a semi-colon as a list delimiter instead of a comma. The semi-colon makes up about 25% of the Excel installations around the world so if you are going to ask for formula assistance, you will want to a) get used to specifying that you use a semi-colon (usually by way of your own sample formula) and b) familiarize yourself with converting the commas that may be supplied to semi-colons.